# Looking for a 360° object view iPhone app

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a 360° iPhone app that models one object from either a level path around the object or perhaps even a true 360 view from any angle looking in at the object.

This is different than the usual panorama 360° that captures what you see from one point in all directions, but one that allows the illusion of a central object to move and not the point of view (camera) moving.

Answer (score 3):

How about [123D Catch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/123d-catch/id513913018?mt=8)? It is free and allows you to turn your photos into a 3D object.

See a demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aU2s85Zw3A).

[image]

I just recently found another one called Relievos.

> Relievos is a fun and creative tool that turns any picture into a 3D image, just like a sculpture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the perfect app - haven't tried it yet but will shortly: [Youspin](http://youspin.co/)

Answer (score -2):

A cool 360° iPhone app is Dermendar.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. The OP specifically said "not one that records a panorama when you spin the camera 360°". Dermander does exactly that.